# Expanding jqgrid subgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

I have a jqgrid that has a subgrid. How can I expand the subgrid without having to click on the plus sign?

I came across `$("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId);` but am unsure which rowId to use to expand the subgrid.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `$("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId);` in the onSelectRow Event of the grid.

Something like this:

```
jQuery("#jqgrid_id").jqGrid({
...
   onSelectRow: function(rowId){ 
      $("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId); 
   },
...
});
```

**EDITED: on GridComplete event**

```
jQuery("#jqgrid_id").jqGrid({
...
   gridComplete: function(){ 
      var rowIds = $("#jqgrid_id").getDataIDs();
      $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
        $("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId); 
      });
   },
...
});
```

Comment: Can I expand the subgrid without the user having to click on anything? For example, after the jqgrid and subgrid have finished loading, the subgrid is automatically expanded.

Comment: sure in that case use the onGridComplete Event.

Comment: What would I use for the rowID?

Comment: Sorry trevor.  Probably should have been more specific.  Check out my edited answer

Comment: AS mentioned by @Stefan below, Change getDataIds() to getDataIDs()!

Answer (score 1):

Change getDataIds() to getDataIDs()!