# jQuery - jQGrid - expand,collapse subgrid on grid row click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, subgrid

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345401) there is an answer on how to expand a subgrid when we click a row using:

```
onSelectRow: function(rowId) {
    $("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId);
}
```

How can we collapse the row if it has been already expanded?
I am looking for something like:

```
onSelectRow: function(rowId){ 
    if (the_row_of_the_grid is expanded) {
        // collapse: How implement this???
    } else {
        $("#jqgrid_id").expandSubGridRow(rowId);
    }
}
```

to have a complete expand/collapse on row click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but it seems to me that the following code should do what you need:

```
onSelectRow: function (rowId) {
    $("#jqgrid_id").jqGrid ('toggleSubGridRow', rowId);
}
```

(see jqGrid [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid#methods))

Answer (score 2):

i needed the same thing, but i couldn't permit the grid to be expanded in the case where it was already collapsed, so the 'toggleSubGridRow' wouldn't work for me. Better in the situation where only a collapse should be permitted is the 'collapseSubGridRow' method.

```
onSelectRow: function (rowId) {
    $("#jqgrid_id").jqGrid ('collapseSubGridRow', rowId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it wasn't working for me at first xD... I've set selectOnExpand on my subGridOptions, so every time I click an expand it select the row and call onSelectRow once again ahaha... so funny...

Hope this help some fool like me there :)