# jqgrid how to expand/collapse subgrid when click a row

Tags: jqgrid, toggle, subgrid

I need to click a row, and if

1. the subgrid is collapsed, then expand it.
2. the subgrid is expanded, then collapse it.

I found the question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291819/jquery-jqgrid-expand-collapse-subgrid-on-grid-row-click), but @Oleg sugesstion didn't work in my project. I have debuged it and found the "onSelectRow" will be executed twice. for example,

```
    onSelectRow: function (row_id) {
      alert("hello");
    },
```

It will get two alert. So, if I write this:

```
    onSelectRow: function (row_id) {
                $("#grd").toggleSubGridRow(row_id);
            },
```

it will expand and collapse,(actually, I can't see the process, I find it by debugging).
This is my code, please ignore the Chinese in it.

```
jQuery("#grd").jqGrid({
            url:'__APP__/Spot_sales/get_sale_order_masters',
            mtype: 'post',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames:['id','uid','日期','销售单号','客户名称','应收金额','实收金额','状态'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id', hidden:true},
                {name:'uid',index:'uid', hidden:true},
                {name:'order_date',index:'order_date', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'orderNo',index:'orderNo', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'customer',index:'customer', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'sum_money',index:'sum_money', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'receive_money',index:'receive_money', width:100, align:'center'},
                {name:'status',index:'status', width:100, align:'center'}
            ],
            sortname: 'order_date',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            pager:'#pager',
            rowNum:10,
            autowidth: true,
            height:'auto',
            multiselect: false,
            onSelectRow: function (row_id) {
                $("#grd").toggleSubGridRow(row_id);
            },
            subGrid : true,
            subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                "reloadOnExpand" : true,
                "selectOnExpand" : true },
            subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                var subgrid_table_id;
                subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id+"_t";
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>");
                jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                    url:'__APP__/Spot_sales/get_sale_order_details?so_id='+$("#grd").getRowData(row_id)['id'],
                    mtype: 'get',
                    data:{},
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ['id','so_id','产品编号','数量','单位','单价'],
                    colModel: [
                        {name:"id",index:"id",hidden:true},
                        {name:"so_id",index:"so_id",hidden:true},
                        {name:"productNo",index:"productNo",width:100},
                        {name:"quantity",index:"quantity",width:100,align:"right"},
                        {name:"unit",index:"unit",width:80,align:"right"},
                        {name:"price",index:"price",width:100,align:"right"}
                    ],
                    rownumbers: true,
                    height: '100%',
                    sortname: 'id',
                    sortorder: "asc"
                });
            }

        }).navGrid("#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:false,search:false});
```

Comment: Do you make `click` or `doubleclick` on the row which you select? Which web browser you use in your tests?

Comment: @Oleg My browsers are IE and Firefox. I also have this test code 
$("#btn_add1").button().click(function(){
                jQuery('#grd').toggleSubGridRow('1');
            })
It works fine!

Comment: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandSubgridOnSelection0.htm) which uses `toggleSubGridRow` and where I see some problems only in case of double clicking. In my tests `onSelectRow` will be executed twice only in case of double clicks. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandSubgridOnSelection1.htm) uses `expandSubGridRow` only and the user can collapse the subgrid only by clicking on "-" icon, but it has no problems with selection or double click.

Comment: @Oleg I have tried your sugestion of `expandSubGridRow` in second demo, it works fine. Your first demo is exactly what I want, but it have the problem in my project.

Comment: ps: My jqGrid vesion is  4.5.2

Comment: I don't understand what you mean under "it have the problem in my project". Do you tried [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ExpandSubgridOnSelection0.htm)? Is `onSelectRow` called once on the click on some row of the grid?

Comment: I have copied your first demo to my project, it works fine. So I can sure it my problem. I am confused.... Anywhere, thank you Oleg very much.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: @Oleg, I have found the problem. My project have the following code `subGridOptions: { "plusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
                    "minusicon" :"ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
                    "openicon" : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
                    "reloadOnExpand" : true,
                    "selectOnExpand" : true  //this line make the 'onSelectRow' excute again.
                },` the 'selectOnExpand' make the problem. Thank you Oleg!

Comment: It's good news. Congratulations!

Comment: @Oleg Would you please help me at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319725/jqgrid-how-to-add-a-row-in-cell-editing-model)

Comment: this work for me:  $("#grd").toggleSubGridRow(row_id);...jqgrid 5.2

Answer (score 2):

An option is to expand the subgrid on the row click event.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#grd tr.jqgrow", function (e) {
            var id = jQuery('#grd').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            if (id != null) {                     
                    jQuery('#grd').expandSubGridRow(id);                      


            }
        });
```