# jqGrid: How to add a row in "cell editing" model?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to make the jqGrid as Excel style. If the jqGrid's rows are not enough, I can append a row on it. I have checked the wiki, the "addRow" method is only worked in "Inline Editing" model. If I call the "addrow" method, the jqGrid will change into "inline editing" model.

I have searched some similar questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628949/excel-like-enter-and-tab-key-navigation-in-cell-editing/4648574#4648574), but I didn't find any heuristic sugestion for my topic.

ps: Is there a vivid demo of jqGrid as Excel style? Just like a [Handsontable](http://handsontable.com/index.html)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. I don't understand what you mean under "Excel style". If you use cell editing mode and you need add a row you can use [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method. If required you can call [editCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#methods) on the new row. You can use [rowIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_tablerow_rowindex.asp) property of DOM element of new added row to get the index of the row which you can use as the first parameter of `editCell`.

Comment: Your are the master of jqGrid, thank you very much. the "addRowData" method is exactly the answer!