# Font awesome not display in IE9 and FF(Simple example)

Tags: font-awesome

I am new of Font awesome. I have written a simple example following the Font awesome demo, but it did not work? it did not display the camera, why? please help me. The simple example is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body >
    <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> fa-camera-retro
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `http:` or `https:` prefix to the URL. For example

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
```

You asked some previous questions about jqGrid. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FontAwesome4_.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20165553/315935) as an example of usage of Font awesome inside of jqGrid.

Comment: Thank you! But this example can not display icons in my IE9.0. another question: Would you please help me on [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319725/jqgrid-how-to-add-a-row-in-cell-editing-model)

Comment: @fujianfeng: Thanks, I fixed the code of the demo to work in IE8/IE9. About your another question: sorry, but I don't understand it. Could you modify the text of the question to include more detailed. The statements like "... to make the jqGrid as Excel style" can be interpreted in different ways. The reference on [another product](http://handsontable.com/index.html) looks for me like [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing).